# Translate Validation Error Message of Date of Birth

Tags: localisation

I got a problem to translate validation error message "Please enter a valid full date." in the edit account page. This message will be prompted when user leave Date of Birth field is empty.

That field was using js/varien/js.js to validating the user input. I failed to translate the error message which was assigned to a JavaScript variable namely, error.

(js.js code in Magento ver 1.7.0.2)

```
    validate: function() {
    var error = false,
        day = parseInt(this.day.value.replace(/^0*/, '')) || 0,
        month = parseInt(this.month.value.replace(/^0*/, '')) || 0,
        year = parseInt(this.year.value) || 0;
    if (!day && !month && !year) {
        if (this.required) {
            error = 'This date is a required value.';          <------ (Line: 445)
        } else {
            this.full.value = '';
        }
    } else if (!day || !month || !year) {
        error = 'Please enter a valid full date.';          <------ (Line: 450)
```

For above error messages, simply adding translation text into translate.csv did not work. Please help how to translate these strings without changing the core code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add translation part in locale file:

```
magento\app\locale\YOUR PACAKGE(like en_EN,fr_FR)\Mage_Core.csv
```

It will reflect when it will translating message. I have work with this so.

Comment: Just added to Mage_Core.csv, but no result. Should we touch the jstranslator.xml file ? I noticed those messages would be added via Javascript Translate object.

Comment: I don't recommended that because  it is core files so..

Comment: Shared the same view. I also feel uncomfortable to edit the core. Any advice?

Comment: I am finding some solutions and let you know ..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new module containing the translations. In the translations you need to prefix the entry with the name of the core-module, **e.g. Mage_Core::Advanced**.

Using this technique you can change translations without changing a core file due to the order that Magento is reading the translation files. The technique is described in detail here: http://www.code4business.de/magento-core-texte-uebersetzen/

Answer (score 0):

These messages are translated with the JavaScript `Translator` object, which is initialized based on `jstranslator.xml` files. These again use the normal translation methods, so as soon as the string to be translated is included in a `jstranslator.xml` file, you can use `translate.csv` as usual

These particular translations are coming from `Mage_Core` and are present in `jstranslator.xml` (you can verify that this is working if you search for the string in the HTML source code in your browser. You should find it in the `Translator` initialization`).

This is what you have to place in `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/[language]/translate.csv`:

```
"Mage_Core::This date is a required value.","..."
"Mage_Core::Please enter a valid full date.","..."
```

#### Update:

There is actually a bug in the translation files: In "Please enter a valid full date" the period at the end is missing, so you need to add  `jstranslator.xml` in an own module and change the string there.

It's explained here: [Please enter a valid full date translate](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46126/please-enter-a-valid-full-date-translate)